# VS2017 hangs when adding a user control to a form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

I have a user control modified from this one:
https://github.com/navhaxs/media-control-deskband

I registered this user control using the tools in it and I added a new WinForms project to visualize the control. First time I did it it worked ok, but when I changed it  the changes are not reflected in the winform (it still using the original one... although I recompiled it) and when I deleted and re-added it to the form it hangs VS2013... any ideas?

**Edit**:
As Hass Passant comment suggested I checked devenv.exe in Task Manager. The CPU usage is just around the 1%
[image: Task manager and hanged VS2017 screenshot]

Comment: Use Task Manager and look at the CPU usage for devenv.exe.  When you see it burn 100% core then you know that code in the user control that runs at design time is not behaving well.  Pretty common bug, github.com is the new codeproject.com scourge to humanity.  Either delete it so it can do no further harm or show us a repro.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot the cpu usage is around 1% @HansPassant

Comment: Well, it was worth a guess.  Now what are we supposed to do to help you?  Show repro code.  If you don't want to then just file a bug with the github.com project.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem. Decision:

1. Take out the Control that you use as DeskBand, into a separate UserControl. Do not use any Com registrations on it and do not inherit any interfaces and classes except UserControl.
2. Paste the control from the first step into your DeskBand control and specify property Dock as **Fill**.
3. Paste the control from the first step into your WinForms project.

Comment: Yes but... if I don't use the Com registrations then it couldn't be used as a deskband (that is the final objective)

Comment: You can freely register the second control, because it will not be directly used in the WinForms project and will not cause a hang

Comment: If you mean the creation of DeskBand without Com registration, this is not possible, because explorer.exe uses the registry to expand the shell. Of course, you can add entries to the registry manually or in code, but this will be the same as regasm